# Symfony 3.4, usar parameters.yml en controlador

Tags: symfony

Quiero leer un registro de `parameters.yml` en un controlador.
No sé por qué pero con Swift Mailer me funciona, pero no de otra forma. Esto estoy intentando:

```
//Mi Controller
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    function someMethod($argument)
    {
        dump($this->getParameter('free_proxy'));die();
```

Acá tengo en parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    free_proxy: "http://xxx:8080"
```

Obtengo el error: `Call to a member function getParameter() on null`

Intenté además así:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
        bind:
          $freeProxy: '%free_proxy%'
```

Y de ahí con:

```
$this->container->getParameter('free_proxy');
```

Y obtengo: `Unused binding "$freeProxy" in service...`

¿Cómo entonces poder usar un simple registro en el controlador? Como dije, con Swift Mailer no hay problema cuando uso:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()->setSubject($this->getParameter('mailer_subjet'))  etc...
```

puedo leer "mailer_subject" que está en parameters.yml, pero por qué no el otro?

Answer (score 0):

Te falta llamar antes al container, te adjunto un ejemplo:

```
dump($this->container->getParameter('free_proxy'));
```

Y solo debe estar creada en parameters.

Quita lo que has creado en services.